# AS3 startDrag() only drags part of MC....leaves children (buttons and texts) behind

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have a MC of a Timer that I created.  Inside the MC there are buttons to set a countdown time and to clear it, some buttons to start and reset the timer, and a dynamic text field to display the time.  Each of the buttons have event listeners and detailed code inside.

On the stage, I have a button, that does an addchild(timer) to the stage, and then I make it draggable.  However, when I drag it, only my first layer, the background layer drags, and the rest of the movie clip stays put.  I added a button mode to the timer, but the hand only shows up over the background, not over the area where the time text is.  Is there something else I should be doing to drag the entire container around the screen?

```
function addATimer(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var _timer:mc_timer = new mc_timer;
    dragArray.push(_timer);
    _timer.x = 260;
    _timer.y = 157;
    _timer.buttonMode = true;
    addChild(_timer);
    _timer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
    trace (dragArray);
}


// function for the start dragging event. 
function startDragging(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    draggedObject = MovieClip(event.target)
    draggedObject.startDrag();
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);  
}


//function to stop the draggable object.  
function stopDragging(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    draggedObject.stopDrag();
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);   
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`.

Comment: really?...really?  Worked like a charm!  3 hours later and I Wish I knew these things!  I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `event.target` references whatever you clicked on (which can also be a child of the `DisplayObjectContainer` that you added the listener to.

`event.currentTarget` on the other hand is always a reference to the object that you added the listener to.

In your case, it makes sense to add the code related to drag&drop functionality to the class `mc_timer`.